# How to put XML returned by stored procedure in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, variables

I have stored procedure returning XML. XML returned not as parameter but as result of SELECT:

```
create procedure #xml_test
as
  select 1 as a for xml raw
go
```

I'm trying to put this XML in a variable:

```
declare @xml as nvarchar(max)
```

But I can't find how to do it. My best idea was INSERT INTO ... EXEC, but I get error 'The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.':

```
create table #tmp(col1 nvarchar(max) not null)

insert into #tmp
exec #xml_test
```

This approach works well for usual text:

```
create procedure #text_test
as
  select 'aaa' as a 
go

insert into #tmp
exec #text_test
```

I wonder if somebody bumped into this issue before? I'm on SQL Server 2005

Comment: Can't you just return it as an Output parameter instead? If so this approach should do what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914009/saving-the-for-xml-auto-results-to-variable-in-sql

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change stored procedure :(

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few examples of SELECTing from XML into variables on this page:

What's New in FOR XML in Microsoft SQL Server 2005
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28SQL.90%29.aspx

The simplest example given is:

```
DECLARE @cust XML;
SET @cust = (SELECT * FROM Customers FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
```

---

Okay, after suitable admonishment for a silly, ill thought-out comment, here is an answer which I hope is somewhat better.  It uses the OPENROWSET to store the results of a stored procedure into a temporary table.  From there, the results can be passed to a variable.  It's a bit messy, and requires ALTER SETTINGS server-level permission to enable Ad Hoc Distributed Queries.

Anyway, here's the fully tested T-SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_test;
GO

USE [db_test];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE xml_test
AS
    SELECT 1 AS a FOR XML RAW
GO

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

SELECT * INTO #tbl_test FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        'SQLNCLI',
        'Server=(local);trusted_connection=yes',
        'set fmtonly off exec db_test.dbo.xml_test') AS tbl_test;
GO

DECLARE @xml_test AS XML;
SET @xml_test = (SELECT * FROM #tbl_test FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64);
GO
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this article when I search for an answer. Unfortunately it deals with SELECTs only. I have to get XML from stored procedure.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I had misunderstood that bit.  How about "EXEC @xml = xml_test()"?

Comment: No, it is complete nonsense. I would suggest you to do some testing before answering.

Comment: @Mike - Nice Answer - Doesn't seem possible to avoid the BASE64 encoding though?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I didn't find a way to avoid BASE64 with XML RAW, but it may be possible with other modes - I didn't spend much time trying to find a solution to that bit. BASE64 does seem like a rather unfortunate consequence though.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to wrap the SELECT so that it sets a local variable and then SELECT that at the end of your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xml_test
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @xml

    SET @xml = (SELECT 1 AS a FOR XML RAW)

    SELECT @xml AS my_xml
END
```

There are some gotchas with using FOR XML though, so if you have subqueries, unions, etc. then you might need to rework the query slightly.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not change stored procedure.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck... :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem kept me busy for some time.

I have a function that generates an xml variable with the diff of two input xml variables.

This is how I'm able to return the result.

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetXmlDiff]
(
    @id uniqueidentifier,
    @left XML,
    @right XML
)
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Delta TABLE
    (
        id uniqueidentifier,
        Delta NVARCHAR( 10 ),
        Attribute NVARCHAR( MAX ),
        Value NVARCHAR( MAX )
    );
        ---
    --- DO THE DIFFING INTO  table VARIABLE
        ---
    DECLARE @ResultVar XML = (
    SELECT * FROM  ( 
                        SELECT  1 AS tag, 
                                null as parent, 
                                id   AS 'o!1!id',
                                null AS 'a!2!delta',
                                null AS 'a!2!name',
                                null AS 'a!2!!element'
                                 FROM @Delta 
                        UNION
                        SELECT  2 as tag, 
                                1 as parent, 
                                id,
                                Delta,
                                Attribute,
                                Value
                                 FROM @Delta 
                    ) Q 
                    FOR XML EXPLICIT );
    RETURN @ResultVar;
END
```

---

The function will now generate a XML variable with a content like:

---

```
<o id="4CBA2CC4-1FB6-426E-8504-0000468CD7E5">
  <a delta="Add" name="attribute1">value 1</a>
  <a delta="Delete" name="attribute2"></a>
  <a delta="Update" name="attribute3">value 3</a>
 </o>
```

---

---