# Saving Dynamic query result into variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a variable (@a) with query:

```
    select Field1 as [TD],Field2 as [TD]
from MLSFeed 
For XML raw('tr'), Elements
```

How to save `xml` result (`dynamic query`) into another variable (@b)?

I tried to create Temporary table and insert there result of DynamicSQL, but that doesn't allow to enter xml result into table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving the FOR XML AUTO results to variable in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914009/saving-the-for-xml-auto-results-to-variable-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @MyOutput NVARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT @MyOutput = (SELECT s.name FROM sys.databases s FOR XML AUTO)'
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@MyOutput nvarchar(max) OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @MyQuery
    ,@ParmDefinition
    ,@MyOutput = @MyOutput OUTPUT;

SELECT @MyOutput
```

You will need to replace the variables and tables as required. Let us know.

Comment: Thanks. That Worked

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable and fill it. Without dynamical qry.

```
declare @a xml
set @a = (
    select Field1 as [TD],Field2 as [TD]
    from MLSFeed
    for xml raw('tr'), elements)

--select @a

declare @b xml -- you asked for @b
set @b = @a
```

You shouldn't use dynamical qry without reason.